# Actualizar precios por lotes productos de woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Soy nuevo con wordpress y estoy intentando actualizar por lotes el precio de todos los productos que tengo en un Woocommerce.

Lo estoy haciendo a traves de un query directa a la bd de wordpress. Para evitar el timeout del servidor (No puede actulizar todos los productos de una pasada) con un limit y offset dentro de la consulta.

El problema es que no encuentro (aun) la forma de recuperar algun valor (en mi caso queriendo saber o gurdar el ultimo offset) para  ir haciendo la consulta por lotes y poder ejecutarla correctamente con un cron.

Tal vez alguien me pueda orientar.

Esta es la idea:

```
// functions.php
function set_prices(){

global $wpdb;
    $conn = mysqli_init();
    mysqli_real_connect( $conn, server, dbuser, dbpassword, dbname );
    //obtener todos los productos que estan publicados
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'product' OR post_type = 'product_variation' limit 0, 100");
    
    // Obtener los SKU por ID
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare( "SELECT meta_value as sku FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE post_id = ? and meta_key='_sku'");
    
    // Actualziar el precio en postmeta
    $stmt3 = $conn->prepare( "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta SET meta_value = ? WHERE (meta_key = '_price' or meta_key = '_regular_price') AND post_id = ?"); 

        $stmt1->execute();
        $res = $stmt1->get_result();
        
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
            $id= intval($row['ID']);
            $stmt2->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $res2= $stmt2->get_result();
            if($stmt2->affected_rows != 0 && $stmt2->affected_rows !=-1){

                $sku_get=$res2->fetch_assoc();
                $sku=intval($sku_get['sku']);
                // conexion de un ws que debvuelve el precio del producto a traves del sku
                $stmt3->bind_param("di",$price,$id);
                        $stmt3->execute();
                        $res3= $stmt3->get_result();
                }
            else{
                continue;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No te funciona mejor un plugin? No te complicas la vida y a parte de eso es desechable. Te presento algunas opciones:

1. WooCommerce Advanced Bulk Edit
2. WooCommerce Advanced Bulk Edit
3. YITH WooCommerce Edición de productos a granel
4. Productos y precios variables de edición masiva de WooCommerce

Pero si eres de los que prefiere el codigo De igual manera te presento una solucion con JSON que podrias intentar:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfUL7SJ8RJM